# Какое отличие между параметрами compileSdkVersion и targetSdkVersion?

Tags: android, gradle

Какое отличие между параметрами `compileSdkVersion` и `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: Вот тут есть в точности такой же вопрос. Можно иногда и поискать прежде чем писать. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion

Comment: @dubok79 я видел этот ответ, но не полностью его понял. Вот и решил задать вопрос здесь.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Немного дополню исходный ответ (по ссылке из комментария @dubok79) + попытаюсь объяснить на пальцах.

`compileSdkVersion` - та версия SDK, с которой будут собираться билды. По большому счету, влияет на всевозможные сообщения отладки. В финальный билд само SDK, конечно же, никак не "зашивается", более того, даже упоминания об этой настройке в нем не будет.

Лично я стараюсь держать ее равной `targetSdkVersion`. В теории возможна, например, следующая ситуация (чисто выдуманная, но логика должна быть понятна). С новой версией SDK несколько методов стали deprecated. Если повысить значение параметра, будем получать предупреждения при сборке проекта. Однако в данный момент команде надо срочно делать новый функционал, избавлением от устаревшего получится заняться только по завершении. Тогда лучше не повышать, чтобы среди игнорируемых пока предупреждений не пропустить важные.

`targetSdkVersion` - максимальная версия, под которую вы проверяли свое приложение. Это нужно Android, чтобы понимать - можно ли использовать свежий функционал в приложении или оно может оказаться к нему не готово. Помогает избегать ситуаций, когда с обновлением версии оси поменялись какие-то значения / поведения по-умолчанию, от чего ваше приложение может начать работать хуже. Пример, приходящий в голову: когда обязательность кнопки меню убрали и заменили на ActionBar.

Опять же, в моем случае стараюсь держать этот параметр всегда актуальным последней версии оси. Но переход - это всегда необходимость проверить, не сломалось ли чего, комплексно пробежать по приложению. Потому не всегда он делается сразу и быстро.

Comment: "даже упоминания об этой настройке в нем не будет." - кто вам такое сказал? декомпилируйте любой апк из стора и увидите в манифесте все эти значения:
platformBuildVersionCode="25" platformBuildVersionName="7.1.1"
и <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="25"

Comment: Не вижу расхождений в вашем примере: я писал про отсутствие compileSdkVersion, у вас же minSdkVersion и targetSdkVersion.

Comment: @kpower открыл apk. залез в manifest file и увидел там `android:compileSdkVersion="32"`. Всё-таки он там есть. Интересно для чего

Comment: @VanechikSpace возможно, со временем поменялось (в 2016 должен был проверить, прежде, чем писать). Но "интересно, для чего" - поддержу)))