# В чем смысл два раза указать целевую версию SDK?

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-manifest

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну как то смутно но хоть что то описана ниже скрине, но этого недостаточно, чтобы понять, в особенности, смысл "compileSdkVersion", а насчет targetSdkVersion я только понял, что оно переопределяет соответствующую настройку, указанную в Manifest-е.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Какое отличие между параметрами compileSdkVersion и targetSdkVersion?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494873/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-compilesdkversion-%d0%b8-targetsdkversion)

Comment: @Olmicron ссылка на ваш дубликат не помог, но ссылка, которую я нашел в предложенном вами дубликате - вполне помог.  Если несложно, можете поменять ссылку вашей отметки на эту ссылку? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion